# If post author role is X

Tags: conditional-content

Simplifying how I currently show featured posts, when a post is submitted by a full member, a post_meta value is added to the post which is then styled differently.

But Id like to do it based on the post authors, user role instead.

So if a the user who submitted the post is a "full_member",  their post is automatically featured without the need for post_meta to be queried.

I've tried something like this which is in the archive template loop, and just adds a "featured-listing" class to a wrapping div,  but I don't think I'm looking at it in the correct way.

```
 <?php $user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'full_member', (array) $user->roles ) ) { ?>

featured-listing

<?php } ?>
```

**EDIT**

Part 1 has been resolved using Nathan's original answer for the class issue , his answer has expanded since then which doesnt work for me, so ive pasted the solution that did work below :

```
//* If the post author is a full member, they get a featured listing
function which_class() {
  return post_author_role_in( 'full_member' ) ? 'featured-listing' : 'regular-listing';
}

//* Determine if the post author is in the $role
function post_author_role_in( $role ) {
  return in_the_loop() ? user_role_in( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), $role ) : false;
}

//* Determine if the $user_id is in the $role
function user_role_in( $user_id, $role ) {
  return in_array( $role, ( new WP_User( $user_id ) )->roles );
}
```

**Part 2 However I still need a solution for**

*Id still like to use a conditional* to completely hide certain elements within the template,   is there an **IF condition** which says something like  `IF post author is in X role, display this, else display this`.  ?

Please advise :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is getting the author data and checking it's role with `get_userdata()` [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata)

For that you will need the user ID, and you can get that with `get_post_field()` [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_field)

You will need the post ID to use the `get_post_field()`, so you can use the `get_queried_object_id()`[Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object)

*So, you would have something like:*

```
//gets the ID of the post
$post_id = get_queried_object_id();

//gets the ID of the author using the ID of the post
$author_ID = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );

//Gets all the data of the author, using the ID
$authorData = get_userdata( $author_ID );

//checks if the author has the role of 'subscriber'
if (in_array( 'subscriber', $authorData->roles)):
    //show the content for subscriber role
else:
    //show the content for every other role
endif;
```

Is there a faster/simpler way to do it? **Yes**

So why I gave you this 'around the world' solution'? **Because from my experience, this way you can prevent a lot of stuff that might mess up with your result later on**

So, what about another way of doing it? **Since there are a few ways to do it, you can for example use the `global $authordata`. You can check the globals WordPress has [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables)**

Comment: Thanks for that answer,  the way you have done it makes sense,  although I'm starting to think that maybe im not doing it right or not explaining my needs correctly ?.  This is a paste bin of my loop-archive.php which is used for search results and archives.  I basically want to show featured posts with additional info,  else show the normal loop.  Currently its showing every post as featured, so seems to be ignoring the user role.  https://pastebin.com/gJmhpijm

Comment: Do you have correctly created the user role 'full_member'? You code looks right (at least the one on the paste.bin). You don't really need the $post_id online 27, since you are already inside the post and that info is from that same post.

Comment: Also, does your 'full_member' user has more than 1 role?

Comment: Spot on thank you Marcelo,   the user had indeed got more than one role selected,  the result of testing testing testing :D and getting myself in a muddle.  Thanks very much.

Comment: I will award you my bounty :)  although I can't do it for another 23 hours according to the system so will add it tomorrow :)

Comment: No problem @Randomer11, I had the same issue a few times =p Glad I could help.

Comment: Marcelo can you think of any reason why this would be working on search results pages,  but not on custom taxonomy pages when both are using the same template part loop-archive.php ?

Comment: I have that same code working on a custom post page, regular page and custom taxonomy page. Thats weird. I can't think of a reason for that to happen

Comment: So strange,  it seems to be working only on search results.  No archive or taxonomy listings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68376/discussion-between-marcelo-henriques-cortez-and-randomer11).

Answer (score 4):

I think you're going about it the right way. The only thing I'd do differently is to separate the presentation from the logic. So you'd have:

in the template file:

```
<div class="<?php echo which_class(); ?>">Content</div>
<div class="<?php echo is_member() ? 'featured-listing' : '' ; ?>">Content</div>
```

in your functions.php:

```
//* Return whether the post author is a member
//* This function will only work in the loop
function is_member() {
  return post_author_role_in( 'full_member' );
}

//* If the post author is a full member, they get a featured listing
//* This function will only work in the loop
function which_class() {
  return is_member() ? 'featured-listing' : 'regular-listing';
}

//* Determine if the post author is in the $role
function post_author_role_in( $role ) {
  return in_the_loop() ? user_role_in( get_the_author_id(), $role ) : false;
}

//* Get the author ID
function get_the_author_id() {
  return get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
}

//* Determine if the $user_id is in the $role
function user_role_in( $user_id, $role ) {
  return in_array( $role, ( new WP_User( $user_id ) )->roles );
}
```

Note, you don't want to use `wp_get_current_user()` because that would only feature the posts by the current user and not those by all full_members.

Comment: to test a role, you can directly use the WordPress function https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/user_can : `user_can( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), $role )`

Comment: Thats perfect for the class and makes perfect sense to lay it out in that form.  Nice and tidy thank you. 

Is there also a way of use a conditional in the same way,  so If post author is "full_member", show this,  else show this.